# How the unallocated space in SQL Server affects copying to another SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, database-backups

I am a newbie in SQL Server, I have a task to move the whole SQL Server to another.

I am trying to estimate how much space I need in the new SQL Server.

I ran `EXEC sp_spaceused`

And the following came up:

[image]

When I look into the output, it seems that the Database is using ~122GB (reserved), but when looking in the total database size (mdf + ldf) it is ~1.8 TB.

Does that mean when I copy the Database from the existing SQL Server to a new one I will need ~1.8 TBs into the new?

I am thinking about creating a back-up and copy the back-up to the new Server. How does the back-up takes into consideration the unallocated space? Does the back gets closer to the reserved or the database_size? I understand that this is without taking into consideration the uncompressed in the back-up, which will improve the file size.

Thx for the help.

Comment: If you `BACKUP` and `RESTORE` the database, it'll be *exactly* as it was when you backed it up, unallocated space and all/ As for "copying" the database, that depends how you're doing it. Do you *literally* mean you're going to copy the file (while it's detached from the instance)? If so, then again, you are making a *literal* copy of the file(s), unallocated space and all.

Comment: @Larnu I can think about two ways of moving the SQL Server, the way you've mentioned to move the Backup and Restore. The other is to use SSMS and do a copy. Now, I don't know which one is more efficient.

Comment: @AaronBertrand your comment about the back being much smaller since the allocated space will not be backed-up. How do I verify how much of the log data is being used? I see the log data is ~400GB, I cannot figure out how much out of the 400GB is being used.

Comment: @AaronBertrand would you like to answer the question? So, I can give you credit for the answer to the question.

Comment: Sure, I've consolidated my thoughts into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backup file will be much smaller than 1.8TB, since unallocated pages are not backed up. But the log and data files themselves will be restored to an identical size, so you *will* need 1.8TB on the target in order to restore the database in its current state.

Did you check to see if your log file is large due to some uncontrolled growth that happened at some point and is maybe no longer necessary? If this is where all your size is, [it's quite possible you can fix this before the move](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/29829/1186). Make sure you have a full backup and take at least one log backup, then use `DBCC SHRINKFILE` to bring the log file back into the right stratosphere, especially if it was caused by either a one-time abnormal event or a prolonged log backup neglect that has now been addressed.

I really don't recommend copying/moving the mdf/ldf files ([background](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-file-backups)) or using the SSMS UI to "do a copy" since you can have much greater control over what you're actually doing by using proper `BACKUP DATABASE` and `RESTORE DATABASE` commands.

> How do I verify how much of the log data is being used?

If you're taking regular log backups (or are in simple recovery), it should usually be a very small % of the file. `DBCC SQLPERF(LogSpace);` will tell you % in use for all log files.

To minimize the size that the log will require in the backup file itself, then:

- if full recovery, back up the log first.
- if simple recovery, run a couple of `CHECKPOINT;` commands first.